# PHP LDAP connection using URL

Tags: php, ldap

I have a problem while trying to connect from an Ubuntu server with PHP5 to a LDAP server using URL('ldap://hostname/').
The code works fine when I'm not using the URL format (`$server = 'hostname'`).

The code:

```
$server = 'ldap://hostname/';

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($server, 3268) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {
    $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, 'username', 'password');
    $error_ldap_code =  ldap_errno($ldapconn) ;
    if($error_ldap_code==0) {
        echo 'Connected!!!';
    }
}
```

Edit:

I needed `ldaps`, but I saw that with `ldap` I have the same problem. While the problem related to ldap was solved by adding the port in the URL, I still had the ldaps issue. Anyway, I managed to bypass it by using  `ldap_start_tls ( resource $link )` after connecting using only the hostname (without URL format).

Comment: what do you mean *The code works fine when I'm not using the URL* ?

Comment: @shivan: I mean that it works when using only the hostname, without the URL format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the port in the URL - it's not the standard port 389. So 'ldap://hostname:3268'?

Comment: It does not really solve my problem entirely, since I was trying to use ldaps (and it still not working), but it answers correctly (and it works) the problem I raised.

Comment: Hmm, LDAPS would be on another port, so either specify that port in the URL or preferably if the server is configured for  TLS - connect via normal LDAP URL/port then send the start TLS LDAP operation to start encryption. PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php

Comment: I actually updated my post with the same solution some minutes before your comment, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You can also use 'ldaps://' in the url-string to connect via LDAPS

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using LDAP with SSL , you are not required to specify `ldap://` in 1st parameter of `ldap_connect()` function.

Therefore, `ldap_connect('hostname')` is correct.

Note: For LDAP with SSL , you can use `ldap_connect('ldaps://hostname')` .

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php

Comment: Actually I am trying to use ldaps, hence my problem, but I noticed that it doesn't work for ldap either.